# Efficiently Controlling a Lattice With an Armature?

Tags: animation, modifiers, rigging, lattice

**Setup:**
There is a 6-face cube with a subsurf modifier and all the edges have a crease of 1. The cube is parented to a 3-by-3-by-3 lattice.

**Goal:**
Use an armature to control the lattice for squash-and-stretch and exaggerating movement. You should still be able to use absolute shape keys in order to fine tune the animation, but the big movements are controlled by bones.

[image]

Comment: I have added the blend file.

Comment: What is the problem encountered using an armature?

Comment: Getting the armature to work isn't the issue. The issue I have is to control the parts of the lattice I want to without having to manipulate each individual point, so I want to manipulate multiple lattice points with only one bone and still get results that would be satisfactory. I apologise if I was there unclear.